# Unable to override ThemeData

Tags: flutter, themes

I want to have a different background color in MenuPage. I'm trying to override the themeData - I've followed the themeData tutorial from official flutter page but unable to get the result. do you guys have any suggestion?

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

final ThemeData _themeData = new ThemeData( // app theme
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkNavy,
        canvasColor: lightNavy,
        accentColor: lightNavy,
        primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
            color: darkNavy,
            brightness: Brightness.dark,
            elevation: 10,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(
              color: lightGrey,
            ),
            textTheme: TextTheme(
                headline6: GoogleFonts.crimsonPro(
                    color: darkGrey,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400))),
      
);



class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: _themeData,
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class MenuDashBoard extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MenuDashBoardState createState() => _MenuDashBoardState();
}

class _MenuDashBoardState extends State<MenuDashBoard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
              canvasColor: lightNavy,
              scaffoldBackgroundColor: lightNavy
            ),
      
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 30, left: 20),
            child: Column(
```

My main homeScreen has a dark navy background i want to have a light navy in my Menu page.

Comment: Please add what you've tried so far.

Comment: Mention what kind of theme you want to implement

Comment: @mobina The actual code is very long i'll try to add the important bits. I've  updated the questions with the code

Comment: @Bensel i've already implemented the Theme i just want to override it in Menu page with a different Background Color

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute 'scaffoldBackgroundColor' in theme data, setting to the color you want With this, if you are using the scaffold widget, your background app will have the color you want. See:

```
MaterialApp(
   title: 'App',
   theme: ThemeData(
     scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: YourScreen()
),
```

Comment: I've already added the the scaffoldBackgroundcolor - i want to override that in MenuPage ..

Comment: Oh, I understand. Then you can specify directly on menu page the color of the background. You can use the atribute backgroundColor in the Scaffold Widget

Comment: I tried it already but i doesn't work also the override methods doesn't work as well.. I think Imm missing something.. did you check my code ?

Comment: Yeah, I think you should remove the Theme widget and put the change directly in the Scaffold widget. Can you see? Try to set up the scaffoldBackgroundColor inside the Scaffold widget

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.. I found the solution